# AppDelegate stops getting windowDidResize

Tags: cocoa, delegates, nswindow

I have a single window cocoa app. In appDidFinishLaunching I have [[self window] setDelegate: self]. When the app first launches windowDidResize gets called without issue. After a few actions, it doesn't get called again. I haven't closed the window or called anything to do with the window. Haven't changed the delegate, window or self. If I drop in a few

```
NSLog(@"Window: %@ Self: %@ Delegate: %@", [self window], self, [_window delegate]);
```

it's exactly the same before and after it stops working. I do do a fair bit with the notification center, posting and acting on my own notifications but delegates don't rely on notification center, correct? Any tips on figuring out what's happening here?

Comment: Of course soon after posting I find the problem. I was removing myself from the default notification center and then adding back the observations I needed. Apparently delegates and notifications work together more closely than I had imagined.

Comment: Ashley, I think it's better to delete this question then.